# reactjs typescript how to declare const response = await login

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm working with React and Typescript and I'm logging in as a user.

When I try to access the response var I get the following error:

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
const response: unknown
```

I think I'm not declaring something

This is my complete code:

```
import React, {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { IAuthProvider, IContext, IUser } from "./types";
import { getUserLocalStorage, LoginRequest, setUserLocalStorage } from "./util";

export const AuthContext = createContext<IContext>({} as IContext)

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: IAuthProvider) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = getUserLocalStorage();
    console.log("USEEFFECT");

    if (user) {
      setUser(user);
    }
  }, [])

  async function authenticate(
    username:string,
    password: string
  ) {
    const response = await LoginRequest(username, password);
    const payload = {token: response.token}; //  <---- Problem on this line

    setUser(payload);
    setUserLocalStorage(payload);
  }

  function logout () {
    setUser(null);
    setUserLocalStorage(null);
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{...user, authenticate, logout}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Here is the LoginRequest code invoked in the code above. It could be that the problem is here:

```
import { Api } from "../../services/api";
import { IUser } from "./types";

export function setUserLocalStorage (user: IUser | null) {
  localStorage.setItem('u', JSON.stringify(user));
}

export function getUserLocalStorage () {
  const json = localStorage.getItem('u');

  if (!json) {
    return null;
  }

  const user = JSON.parse(json);

  return user ?? null;
}

export async function LoginRequest (username: string, password: string) {
  try {
    console.log("AQUI");
    const request = await Api.post(
      'login/', 
      {username, password}
    );
    return request.data;

  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This is the code that posts the request:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { getUserLocalStorage } from "../context/AuthProvider/util";

export const Api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
});

Api.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const user = getUserLocalStorage();

    config.headers = {
      Authorization: user?.token,
      // Authorization: "Bearer " + user?.token,
    };

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in `LoginRequest`? That could be anything...

Comment: I changed the question and added the LoginRequest.

Comment: What's in Api.post? an axios request?

Comment: I edited the question and added the Api code. Sorry for the bad wording of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript throws this error because your response has no type in it. First create an interface for your login response

```
Interface ILoginRequest {
   token: string;
}
```

then type your post call in the loginRequest

```
const request = await Api.post<ILoginRequest>(
  'login/', 
  {username, password}
);
```

that way `request` have the type `AxiosResponse<ILoginResponse>` this generic represents the data object inside the AxiosReponse.

as you returns `request.data` in your loginRequest function typescript should automatically type the return function of your method as `ILoginResponse` so

```
const response = await LoginRequest(username, password);
```

response will be of type `ILoginRequest` and now typescript won't throw more errors because it knows that response is an object which have a property token in it

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!!!